# Removing id during click in navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css

Good day everyone! I got a simple question here if this one is possible. Here is the scenario.

I got 3 divs

```
<div id="id1">
 content
</div>

<div id="id3">
 content
</div>

<div id="id2">
 content
</div>
```

in my navbar when click to some pages it will be redirected to those div. But my question is: is it possible in url bar not to show the id? For example when click it will not show like this one `mywebsite.com/about/#id2`

I need some ideas thank you.

Comment: is possible, use `window location hash`

Comment: For usability, you should keep the hrefs in the url bar. This is so that, when someone shares your link, the latter arrives exactly where he was meant to.

Comment: @Mysteryos Thank you for the information, but as of not this is what I really need.

Comment: I don't understand why people keep on giving negative(-5) since im new to community?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
    location.hash=location.hash.replace('#','');
});
```